# How to traverse through the DOM elements of a Extjs grid?

Tags: javascript, dom, extjs, grid

Basically I want to add a td class based on the value it has. I cannot apply this in the renderer because of the nature of the requirement. Meaning, a click event in the ExtJS grid[already rendered] requires revisiting all the rows and apply a td class based on the value/condition it posses. Today we are reloading but we wanted to cut down because of performance.

My idea here is to traverse all the TR of the given grid and add a class based on the value. Any suggestion how to take this forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completed the requirement with the help of Ext.DomQuery.select

for (recordIdx of grid)
Ext.DomQuery.select('.x-grid-cell-inner', grid.getNode(recordIdx));